# Como hacer que los msj con laracast/flash tengan el boton de cierre?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando laravel 5.3. y el paquete laracast/flash
En si los msj se muestran correctamente pero el boton de cierre de la ventana flash no aparece.

Segun la documentacion de laracast ahora no se debe colocar el use.

Asi lo uso:

en el controlador:

```
flash("Se ha editado ".$user->nombre." de forma exitosa!", 'success');
```

En la vista el include

```
@include('flash::message')
```

Esto funciona bien pero no me aparece el boton de cierre de la ventana de exito en este caso, pense que podia ser los navegadores, pero en distintos pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el código de Laracasts/flash, debes hacerlo con el método `important()`:

```
flash("Se ha editado ".$user->nombre." de forma exitosa!", 'success')->important();
```

---

En la vista básica de messages.blade.php se observa que necesita el valor `flash_notification.important` para mostrar el botón de cierre:

```
        @if(session()->has('flash_notification.important'))
            <button type="button"
                    class="close"
                    data-dismiss="alert"
                    aria-hidden="true"
            >&times;</button>
        @endif
```

Dicha información es agregada a la sessión en el método `important()` de **Laracasts/Flash/FlashNotifier.php**

```
/**
 * Add an "important" flash to the session.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function important()
{
    $this->session->flash('flash_notification.important', true);
    return $this;
}
```